# argparse add subparser that starts with a dash

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

I'm trying to create a *Pacman* wrapper in *Python*. I'm having trouble to parse the arguments in the same way *Pacman* does. (Described at  https://man.archlinux.org/man/pacman.8)

In order to parse the arguments, I need to create a sub parser that starts with a dash. E.g. *Pacman* allows us to do:

```
$ pacman --database --asdeps which
```

Here `--asdeps` is specific to the `--database` operation. The following is invalid, if I use the `--files` operation instead of `--database`:

```
$ pacman --files --asdeps
error: invalid option '--asdeps'
```

*Python* has the feature request [Issue 34046: subparsers -> add_parser doesn't support hyphen char '-' - Python tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue34046), which was rejected.

Is there some way I can do this with `argparse`? Or is there some other more flexible argument parsing library, short of parsing the arguments manually?

**Update** I'm guessing in this case, that parsing arguments manually isn't too bad, as the manual says the operation must be the first argument. This makes sense for *Pacman* and for `argparse`. Otherwise `argparse` can't easily know if a flag is the name of a sub command, or an argument of that sub command.

Comment: you have answered your own question.  The rejected request should explain why.